# How can I use in teradata recurcive query?

Tags: teradata, recursive-query

Have a below table,

```
customer ID, code,    start_date, end_date
 124343,     DCW,     2015-07-06, 2016-08-03
 235432,     ABC,     2015-04-26, NULL
 235432,     ABC,     2015-04-26, 2015-06-20
3242342,     ABC,     2015-08-02, 2015-07-28
2332434,     DCW,     2015-02-09, 2015-06-23
2332434,     DCW,     2015-06-23, NULL
```

What to use recurcive query to get output for unique code for each customerID,
1. when customer ID has more than 1 record in table with value in end_date and null in end_date then only records with null end_date. 
2. when customer ID has more than 1 record with start_date, end_date and  start_date equal to end_date for the first record then only record with null end_date or future date than today's date. 
3. end_date more than today's date
Required Output

```
customer ID, code, start_date, end_date
 124343,     DCW,    2015-07-06, 2016-08-03
 235432,     ABC,   2015-04-26, null
3242342,     ABC,    2015-08-02, 2015-07-28
2332434,     DCW,   2015-06-23, null
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!.  Formatting note - don't use <br> in your lists, use the formatting tags (the {} on the toolbar).

Comment: You probably don't need recursion for this, try to check if you can define an ORDER BY which sorts the row you want on top, e.g. `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY customerID
          ORDER BY end_date DESC NULLS FIRST) = 1`

Comment: Getting error. Expected the word RESET after ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Post your sql, not much we can do without it.

Comment: joining two tables in order to get customer_ID who are only in status.

Comment: joining two tables in order to get customer_ID who are only in status. select sah.customer_ID,
coalesce(cast(cast(f.start_date as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')as char(10)),'')
,coalesce(cast(cast(f.end_date as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') as char(10)),''),
 ROW_NUMBER () 
OVER
 (
 PARTITION BY sah.customer_ID
 ORDER BY f.end_date DESC NULLS FIRST ) = 1
 from
  where 
sah.customer_ID = f.customer_ID
  and sah.customer_ID IN  ('A')
  and (f.end_date is null or cast( f.end_date as date format'YYYY-MM-DD')  > cast(current_date as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'))

Comment: The `ROW_NUMBER (...) = 1` must be part of the `QUALIFY`. And if you got an error for `NULLS FIRST` you must be running a Teradata release before TD14.10. Change it to `ORDER BY CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, end_date` instead.